# Dash generalize progress bar

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am developing a data app using dash. I am doing a file copy task for that I am showing the progress bar.

I have written this code from dash website as reference. This is pseduo code structure

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Input, Output, dcc, html, ctx

progress = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Interval(id="progress_interval", max_intervals=500, n_intervals=0, interval=2000),
        dbc.Progress(id="progress"),
    ]
)

copy_button = dbc.Button(id="btn_copy", children="Copy", className="btn btn-success"),

@app.callback(
    [Output("progress", "value"), Output("progress", "label")],
    [
      Input("progress_interval", "n_intervals"),
      Input("btn_copy", "n_clicks")
    ],
)
def update_copy_progress(n):
  triggered_id: Any = ctx.triggered_id
  
        
    # use n_intervals constrained to be in 0-100
    
    if triggered_id == "progress_interval":
       progress = min(n % 110, 100)       
       # only add text after 5% progress to ensure text isn't squashed too much
       return progress, f"{progress} %" if progress >= 5 else ""
       
       
    if triggered_id == "btn_copy":
       # start some background process
       long_running_file_copy_task()
```

The progress bar starts running when clicked on button and display 5% 6% 7%....

say I am copying 100MB file size.
Issues, I noticed:

1. File copied is 10 MB on terminal but on UI progress bar displaying 40%
2. File copy is going on and once progress bar reaches 100% it gets refreshed and starts again from 1%

How in real web application the progress bar is handled say for file copying task for different file sizes and for any long running tasks. How to generalize the progress bar.
Please suggest some direction.

Comment: May be dash-uploader could help. https://pypi.org/project/dash-uploader/

Comment: Hi hoa tran, Thanks. But I was searching to write custom to have more control. Based on searching till now, I think writing generic progress bar is not good approach and different tasks will need to handle self.